# Subselect with where clause

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I need to list data in table with several data. I need to get the amount of games played ('COUNT(p.partie) as sumparties') and the amount of games won.

Here is my repository :

```
    $qb->select('j AS jou')
        ->innerJoin('j.playeds', 'p')
        ->addSelect('SUM(p.points) AS sumpoints')
        ->addSelect('SUM(p.max) AS summax')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(p.partie) as sumparties')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(p.partie) as sumwins WHERE p.points = 1')
        ->groupBy('j.id')
        ->orderBy('sumpoints', 'DESC');
```

So, for the first one it Works :

```
->addSelect('COUNT(p.partie) as sumparties')
```

I get the total games playeds. But I don't manage to get the amount of games won. I tried with this but obviously it doesn't work :

```
->addSelect('COUNT(p.partie) as sumwins WHERE p.points = 1')
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of combining `select` and `where`:

```
->addSelect('COUNT(p.partie) as sumwins WHERE p.points = 1')
```

Split the where clause:

```
->addSelect('COUNT(p.partie) as sumwins')
->andWhere('p.points = 1')
```

---

**Edit:**

As I mentioned in my comment, for your use case you need to do something like this:

`->addSelect('SUM(CASE WHEN p.points = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sumwins')`

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that doesn't work as the Where clause is applied for all the function. I need to apply the where only on this count(p.partie)

Comment: Could you try this instead: `->addSelect('SUM(CASE WHEN p.points = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sumwins')`?